# Does Hugo ( by Jake Wharton) work for different build types?

Tags: android, gradle, hugo

I integrated hugo into my project. The debuglog prints fine for the default "debug" build but not for other build types. Is this expected? Is there a way to make it work for other build types (setting "debuggable true does not help)

Comment: In the documentation, there is nothing to enable for other build types. I think it's only for debug.

Comment: It also states "The logging will only happen in debug builds[...]"